# Google Action apps crashes on some phrases and crashing after account linking

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, assistant

Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of the empty speech response.

I'm always getting this issue on asking the same phrases of a particular intent. Inside the log I checked it is not triggering this intent. Also after account linking the app is crashing. Here is the log.

```
"responseMetadata": { "status": { "code": 10, "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response", "details": [{ "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value", "value": "{\"id\":\"038a5fe6-7464-4fe3-83ea-8412e8c258d4\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-03-13T10:21:56.967Z\",\"lang\":\"en-gb\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHG-wf2qOaZ6G4x_uDV57cxrDj4XrFUUvNAUFYnlZuXKdwqBWlKGxnbbL5VBGP9fTqrYrTRvMYpK\"}" }] } } }.
{
 insertId:  "647th6f88zjhw"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/vguard-smart/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-13T10:21:57.142635383Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "DEBUG"  
 textPayload:  "Received response from agent with body: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.6
Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2019 10:21:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 647
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 4a627d76f2c02dc9c50afa1786f06ba7/7862509189815517582;o=0
Google-Actions-API-Version: 2
Assistant-Interaction-Error-Code: -1
Assistant-Interaction-Error-Message: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response
X-SHARD: shard-1
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear

{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
        "value": "{\"id\":\"038a5fe6-7464-4fe3-83ea-8412e8c258d4\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-03-13T10:21:56.967Z\",\"lang\":\"en-gb\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHG-wf2qOaZ6G4x_uDV57cxrDj4XrFUUvNAUFYnlZuXKdwqBWlKGxnbbL5VBGP9fTqrYrTRvMYpK\"}"
      }]
    }
  }
}."  
 timestamp:  "2019-03-13T10:21:57.110708894Z"  
 trace:  "projects/459929986218/traces/ABwppHG-wf2qOaZ6G4x_uDV57cxrDj4XrFUUvNAUFYnlZuXKdwqBWlKGxnbbL5VBGP9fTqrYrTRvMYpK"  
}
```

Comment: Is your Fulfillment webhook crashing? Do you have any logs from the webhook running? Please update your question with code that is crashing, error logs from the code execution, etc.